Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbQuoteLiteral’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
I have a script in R which, in the final steps, looks to insert data into a MySQL database.
I have previously successfully run this script, but I am now receiving the following error:

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbQuoteLiteral’ for signature ‘"NULL"’

This is the step in my script it's falling down:
con <- Get_DB_Conn("database")
for (i in 1:nrow(master_tib)) {
  print(i)
  x_upsert_list <- as.list(master_tib[i,] %>% 
                                select(-c(Date, Name, Level, qual, round, id)))
  x_upsert_list <- x_upsert_list [!is.na(x_upsert_list )]
  x_sql <- paste0(glue_sql("INSERT INTO database.table1(`{glue_sql_collapse(colnames(master_tib), sep = '`, `')}`)
           VALUES ({master_tib[i,]*})
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ", .con = con),
           paste(paste0("`", names(x_upsert_list ), "`"), 
                 paste0('"', gsub('"', '\\\\"', x_upsert_list ), '"'), sep = " = ", collapse = ", "), ";")
  dbSendQuery(con, x_sql)
}

The below snippet is a step earlier in my script to account for the handling of nulls etc.

safeSQLVar <- function(var) {
  
  ret_vec <- rep("", length(var))
  
  for (i in 1:length(var)) {
    if (is.null(var[i]) | identical(var[i], character(0))) {
      ret_vec[i] <- "NULL"
    }else if (is.na(var[i])) {
      ret_vec[i] <- "NULL"
    } else if (is.character(var[i])) {
      ret_vec[i] <- paste("'", gsub("'", "\\\\'", var[i]), "'", sep = "")
    } else if (is.numeric(var[i])) {
      ret_vec[i] <- as.character(var[i])
    } else if (is.double(var[i])) {
      ret_vec[i] <- paste("'", as.character(var[i]), "'", sep = "")
    } else {
      ret_vec[i] <- var[i]
    }
  }
  
  return(ret_vec)
}

At every step of my script where 'master_tib' is created, I ensure I am accounting for missing values. Could anyone help me with why I might be encountering this problem now when the script has previously worked successfully?
Thanks very much
